# Viewing IDEA 13 Gradle Dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have just switched from IDEA 12 to 13 for better gradle support but noticed that whereas JetGradle in 12 showed your project dependencies in the gradle project window.

However in 13, only Gradle tasks are displayed, rather than also showing your projects dependencies.

Is this simply hidden, been removed permanently or am I just being a bit daft?

Using the Linux distro of IDEA 13 Ultimate edition (although currently on a 30 day trial while I see if it's worth upgrading to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into **Project** -> **External Libraries**. I`m using Ultimate 13.

More:

[Getting Started with Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA 13](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Euo6xzCwY4&list=PLPZy-hmwOdEWxpDkmBBPBvfszt9lruLy_)

Comment: It does not show dependencies of individual modules

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a more fine grained view about dependencies of individual modules:

- Open 'File > Project Structure ...'
- Click on *Modules*
- Choose the module you are interested in
- Click on the tab _Depen[image]